# Customizable curved Line Chart that can show image at various point

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, charts, core-graphics

[image: curved Line chart with image at given point]

I am getting trouble with showing image on line chart at certain point on chart & also i wanted to implement curved line chart with customizable color, width & type (shown in dotted line in image) & labels at x axis & y axis.

I wanted to know is there any iOS libraries are available which provides this kind of implementation.

I know this is  a duplicate question cause there are lot of questions are asked about charts for iOS but all I wanted to know is there is any library available there that can fulfill above requirement & save me lot of time for that implementation.

so far I got following libraries by doing search over google.

1. [JBChartView](https://github.com/Jawbone/JBChartView)
2. [BEMSimpleLineGraph](https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMSimpleLineGraph)
3. [PNchart](https://github.com/kevinzhow/PNChart)

all off above provides line chart implementation but not curved line chart also have no provision for showing image on chart at specified point.

I am very new to chart in iOS so any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the code for curved line chart ? which you've got working so far and which doesn't have support of images as you want ? After having that it would be easier for someone to help you out at showing images.

Comment: @SabirAli Thanks for your interest, i have almost achieved it using BEMSimpleLineGraph , though i have to modify it to show image at give point but it works well enough for now

Answer (score 0):

**Following lines can add image at given points(100,200), which will serve your purpose for drawing image.**

I have developed a sample chart Library in which you will get what you need, kindly go through it. [Download Library here](https://github.com/DipenPanchasara/ChartView)

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley.png"];
[image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100,200)];
```

Comment: @P R J I have added curves in my library. Enjoy...!!!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [SwiftCharts](https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts) for this, it's specially designed for this kind of situations. You can add multiple layers on top of each other and generate custom views (UIView subclasses, which can be an image view or anything else) in any of these layers.

In this case you would add a layer with the curve and another layer on top of it with your custom overlays.

To produce the custom overlays you receive the complete state of each chart point, so for example you can decide if you display the image or not, or customize the image according to the chartpoint's data. See this [example](https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts/blob/master/Examples/Examples/Examples/NotificationsExample.swift):

[image]

There the warning (called notifications in the example) overlays are shown only when the y value is less than 1.

There's also an [example with curved line](https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts/blob/master/Examples/Examples/Examples/CubicLinesExample.swift)

[image]

You could use the curved line example as basis and copy-paste the notifications layer from notifications example to it and add to the chart's layers. Then customize accordingly.

(Disclosure: I'm the author)